# How would you separate the Javascript for modals from the html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS with Javascript. I am currently trying to separate the Javascript code from the html file for modal pop-up functionality. I haven't learned jquery yet, so if there is a way to solve this without it, it would be greatly appreciated.

The complete code can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modal.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Image Modal</h2>
    <img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

External Javascript code:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

The above method doesn't work. When I click on the picture, there is no modal pop-up. I am guessing simply linking the script is not enough, but I am not fluent enough in the language to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put your script tag inside the body.like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Image Modal</h2>
    <img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">×</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="your url"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To provide a better answer, you should describe why this solves the problem

Comment: the browser  import the js is sync. so when you import your js file, your dom html are not ready in dom tree(not instantiation). you can't get the dom object in js.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. So the problem was I should put the script in the body. Why, in this case, does the script not work in the <head>?

Comment: you need run your JavaScript code after the html loaded.otherwise you can't get your dom element.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to link it in any kind. Embedding the js is enough. But youve made a mistake. The page is parsed from top to bottom. The javascript runs before the html has completely loaded. So things like getElementById wont work because the element is not existing at that moment.
To run code when the page is loaded do this js:

```
window.onload=function(){
//do awesome stuff
yourelement=document.getElementById("yourelement");
}
```